# Vim script: How to swap a line with multiple lines?

Tags: vimscript

In a Vim function, I want to append `\` and carriage return after `AND`.

I modify the line using the following expression:

```
let new_line = substitute(new_line, ") AND (", ") AND \\\n (", "g")
```

Now `new_line` contains multiple lines.

How to swap the current line with the content of `new_line`?

Currently I have to run the below commands to output multiple lines:

```
let new_line = substitute(new_line, ") AND (", ") AND \\\\r (", "g")
:call setline(".", new_line)
:s/\\r/\\\r/g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might know; but always remember that when operating on strings in VIM script most (all?) functions do not know or care about what a line is.

https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#string-match

There is a layer between buffer and file written to disk. When a file is read into a buffer VIM detects line-endings, *fileformat*, and replaces them internally; As to mean a buffer is end-of-line byte(s) agnostic. *Look at it as a list.* When writing to disk the lines are joined by [`<EOL>`](https://vimhelp.org/intro.txt.html#%3CEOL%3E) according to *fileformat*.

When one are working with string functions like `substitute()` etc. VIM does not know (or try to detect) what line endings are, e.g. `\n` vs `\r\n`. This is also why one typically use lists instead of strings when working with *multiple lines* in buffers from scripts. This way one do not need to worry about *fileformat*. One typically *get* multiple lines as a list and *put* multiple lines using lists. This is also why for example `$` does not mean end-of-line in a string, but end-of-string, `\n` means literal `LF` / `0x0a` and not end-of-line etc.

Also note for example `:h substitute()`

> […] the matching with {pat} is always done like the 'magic'
> option is set and 'cpoptions' is empty (to make scripts
> portable).

You have some options e.g. `append()` and `setline()`. Both can take a *list* as input. For example by using `append()` you can do something like:

```
"" Get line, substitue and split to list
let list = getline('.')
    \ ->substitute(') AND (', ') AND \\\n(', 'g')
    \ ->split('\n')
"" Delete current line
delete _
"" Append
call append(line('.') - 1, list)
```

Note that if you use `setline()` you would first have to *make room* for the new lines as it replaces (set) lines.

Comment: Apology my fault, I want a single '\'. Question updated.

Comment: @Fisher No worries. Updated. Only sample code anyway. Hope my ramblings are readable ;), - my phrasings could have been better.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
let n = line('.')
let new_lines = split(new_line, ') AND \zs\ze(')
for i in range(len(new_lines) - 1)
    let new_lines[i] = new_lines[i] . '\'
endfor

call deletebufline('%', n)
call appendbufline('%', n - 1, new_lines)
```

Here is some explanation about the steps:

1. The `split` call split your line into subline with `) AND (` as separator.
2. The `\zs` makes that the separator stay with the previous line.
3. The `deletebufline` deletes the current line.
4. The `appendbufline` insert the new lines.